# Bugzilla, how to search in the description of the bug reports

Tags: bugzilla, bug-reporting

I am searching for bug reports in Mozilla Bugzilla, and I am trying to search for my strings in the description of the bug reports.

I do see the options to search in Summary, and Comments in the custom search. 
And I know description is considered as a comment.

But is there any way to only search within description?